# Outer div not expanding as inner div grows

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div that is used to give a background colour to the page and an inner div to put the content in.

As the content expands the inner div is expanding but it does not expand the outer div. I think I know what the issue is but I do not know how to fix it. I am using vh to set the height of the div, when I switch "100vh" to 100%, it fixes the problem and the outer div expands as it grows but if the inner div does not span the page then the outer div does not either and the background colour only shows for half the page. My last attempt was to try "max(100%, 100vh)" but this did the same thing as 100%. Any help?

Also I set the inner div to inline-block because it fixed the top margin from collapsing, I'm not sure if this is causing me problems.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #4f4949;
}

.outer {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: 15vw;
  margin-right: 15vw;
  background-color: #eff4fa;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 15vh;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

This first picture is when I use 100vh as outer div height, it does not expand as inner div grows.
[image]

In the second picture I used 100% as outer div height. It does expand as inner div grows but the background colour does not span the page unless inner div does.
[image]

Edit: I added some HTML Markup showing the layout of my file. The expanding fields come from my react application adding html divs with some text input fields to the DOM.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please include enough HTML and CSS to constitute a [mcve]? Preferably as a snippet in the question?  I'm afraid this question probably can't be adequately answered without your markup.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I added the layout of my divs. The content in the inner div is created using React, it is adding divs within it with some content but I don't think that that content is affecting the outer div here.

Comment: the outer div has a fixed height and overflows. Either set a `min-height` instead of a fixed height or add an overflow rule

Answer (score 2):

Solved, thanks to tacoshy.

I had to set a min-height attribute

```
.outer {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```